# can't get the data from edit function using Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I created the CRUD application with Laravel 5.6. I created the resource controller to do the function. In controller (Index and Create) functions are working fine but edit function I try to echo the variables it's showing blank. I can't understand why is that. Please help to fix these issues.

**Model File**

```
<?php

namespace Asset_Management_System;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class assetType extends Model
{
    //
}
```

**Controller File**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Asset_Management_System\assetType;

public function edit(assetType $assetTypes)
{
    $arr['assetTypes'] = $assetTypes;
    return view('assets.asset_types.edit')->with($arr);
}
?>
```

**URL Path**

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/AssetTypes/1/edit
```

**Route**

```
Route::resource('AssetTypes','AssetTypeController');
```

When I click the edit button it's going to edit page but data is coming.

**Error Message**

**Missing required parameters for [Route: AssetTypes.update] [URI: AssetTypes/{AssetType}]. (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Asset_Management_Laravel\resources\views\assets\asset_types\edit.blade.php)**

I attached the error message screenshot also.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The URL path is a GET path to show something like a form. Data will be shown because you are loading an instance of assetType but not using view();

You should have something like this

```
public function edit(assetType $AssetTypeData)
{
    return view('assetType.edit', ['assetType' => $AssetTypeData]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should get $id in edit method args

```
Route::put('user/{id}', 'UserController@update');



<?php

  namespace App\Http\Controllers;

  use Illuminate\Http\Request;

  class UserController extends Controller
  {
    /**
   * Update the given user.
   *
   * @param  Request  $request
   * @param  string  $id
   * @return Response
   */
  public function update(Request $request, $id)
  {
      //
  }
 }
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/controllers#resource-controllers